# React Native Hooks initializer not taking the correct value

Tags: react-native

What I am trying to do is sync a list of attendees from an online database, and if the current user is in the list, then disable a button, else enable the button.
I am using react native hook (I am not sure if I am using the term correctly as I am fairly new to react), in order to set the value of disabling the button.
The issue that I am facing is that the value is getting initialized to false, even tho it should clearly get initialized to true.
After adding some logging I made sure that the function is executing correctly and reaching  the code where it sets the value to true.

```
const [buttonDisabled, changeButtonState] = useState( () => {
    var database = firebase.database();
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var Attendees = [];
    var disable = false;
    dbRef.child("gameAttendees").child(gameinfo.gameID).get().then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        Attendees = snapshot.val().Attendees;
        for(var i=0;i<Attendees.length;i++){
          if(Attendees[i]==userId){
            return true;
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log("no value");
        return false;
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Your initializer function returns undefined. You can't initialize a component asynchronously. Instead, you'll want to program it to be reactive (hence the name). In your case you'll want to use a mount effect to set the state.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an example of an async mount effect:

```
const Comp = () => {
  const [s, setS] = useState(); // State will be undefined for first n renders

  useEffect(() => {
    // Call the async function and set the component state some time in the future
    someAsyncFunction().then(result => setS(result));
  }, []); // An effect with no dependencies will run only once on mount

  return </>;
};
```